# How do I grant user permissions to protected registry keys in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: registry, windows-server-2012-r2, ntfs

I'm running an installer executable on a Windows Server 2012 machine.  It fails with a custom action script error trying creating a virtual directory on IIS.  I see msiinstaller warning events at the same time that say: "The application tried to modify a protected Windows registry key..." where the keys are subkeys of Software\Classes. When I open regedit and try to change permissions to these keys I get an "Access Denied" error.

How do I grant permissions through regedit to administrators on Software\Classes and its subkeys?

Answer (score 0):

Try granting the access to the user that is running the installer.

For more information, please see [How to apply permissions to a Windows registry key](https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/13811).